# How to create file with list of duplicate values using linux shell?

Tags: linux, file, bash, shell, zsh

I have a text file which contains a list of values:

```
ASDSAV
ASDSAD
ASDFSA
```

and need to get

```
ASDSAV        7
ASDSAD        7
ASDFSA        7
```

i.e. join it with a file that is just one column of 7s (which can be easily achieved with paste)

```
7
7
7
```

Is there easy command to create this file of 7s?

Comment: I never really used sed or awk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0, "7"} ' inputfile > newfile
```

There is no need for a separate file of 7's

Answer (score 2):

The question is actually how to create a file with a list of sevens.

You can use some coreutils:

```
printf '7\n%.0s' $(seq $(wc -l < file)) > output.txt
```

or `awk`:

```
awk '{ print "7" > "output.txt" }' file
```

or `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*/7/' file > output.txt
```

Comment: touchè i guess we assumed pasting wasn't efficent

Answer (score 1):

awk '{print $1 "   7"}' temp.dat;
where temp.dat is your original file.

Answer (score 1):

ALMIGHTY **SED**

```
sed -e "s/$/7/" f1 > f2
```

MAY YOUR AWKS CRUMBLE BEFORE HIS FEET

side note: if u want to tab the 7 out in sed it would be

```
sed -e "s/$/<ctrl+v><tab>7/" f1 > f2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yes` command provides an unlimited supply of its argument:

```
yes 7 | head -n $(wc -l < file.txt) | paste file.txt -
```

(It's good to know about `yes`, but in this case it's a bit clunky. `paste` auto-extends shorter input files with empty lines, and the `yes`-supplied standard input is infinitely long without the `head` to limit it.)